# XSB Runtime errors - MulVal

Tags: prolog, xsb

I'm trying to convert an Nessus scan xml file to MulVal input using a given conversion script and get the following runtime errors:

```
Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Permission (Operation) redefine on imported predicate: lists : member / 2]  in compile/1

Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Existence (No procedure usermod : vulProperty / 3 exists)]
```

..and a few more similar 'no procedure usermod : ...' errors

I haven't worked with XSB/Prolog before so if anyone has any idea whats going on or if you want to see some of the source code please let me know

Comment: Hard to advise without the source of that conversion script.

Comment: https://github.com/fiware-cybercaptor/mulval/blob/master/utils/nessus_translate.sh @PauloMoura